# Buggy jQuery Navbar Popout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got one of those navigation bars that popup and stay ontop when you scroll the page but the problem is when u scroll over from it being on the page to being popped out the rest of the page jumps up a little.

Here is the jquery: (excuse the echo's)

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "$(function() {";
        // grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
        echo "var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#navbar_container').offset().top;";

        // the function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
        echo "var sticky_navigation = function() {";
            echo "var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();"; // our current vertical position from the top

            // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
            // otherwise change it back to relative
            echo "if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {";
                echo "$('#navbar_container').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });";
            echo "} else {";
                echo "$('#navbar_container').css({ 'position': 'relative' });";
            echo "}";   
        echo "};";

        // run our function on load
        echo "sticky_navigation();";

        // and run it again every time you scroll
        echo "$(window).scroll(function() {";
        echo "sticky_navigation();";
        echo "});";
    echo "});";
echo "</script>";
```

If you really slowly just scroll down a bit to make it pop out and watch the body of the page jump up a bit, i'm trying to make that not happen so it's really smooth as it pops out. (it happens popping out and back in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the navigation has `position: fixed;` set when it scrolls down, which means it is no longer embedded in the page, which means the whole page loses that much height, which causes it to "jump up". (Hope that made sense.)

Try adjusting it to something like this:

```
echo "if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {";
    echo "$('#navbar_container').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });";
    echo "$('body').css({ 'margin-top': 45});";
echo "} else {";
    echo "$('#navbar_container').css({ 'position': 'relative' });";
    echo "$('body').css({ 'margin-top': 0});";
echo "}";
```

Comment: Aha ha! worked (near) perfectly (was the container jumping not the body), i'll accept in a few mins, tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, use bootstrap, which will cater to mobile devices too!  Their "Fixed Top" example, showcases a menu that stays on top all the time!

[Fixed Top example, Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)

Answer (score 0):

Put your navbar into another container - give that container a fixed height and then it will not pop out any longer

```
<div class="navbar_surrounding">
<div id="navbar_container" style="position: relative;">
...
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.navbar_surrounding {
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
}
```